# How to check javascript across domains?

Tags: javascript

Trying to check a version across domains.
Here is the code on JS Bin so you can see how it's not working.
http://jsbin.com/iKaWEFI/12/edit?html,js,output

DOMAIN1 (this is the code at the link in DOMAIN2):

```
function myVersion1(){window.domain2_version="1.0";}
```

DOMAIN2:

```
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/19653021128/version-new.js"></script>
<script>
  function myVersion2() {
    window.domain1_version = "1.0";
  }
  if (myVersion1() == window.domain2_version) {
    document.write("Good");
  } else {
    document.write("Bad");
  }
</script>
```

It says **Bad** but it is supposed to say **Good** because 1.0 on DOMAIN1 is the same as the 1.0 on DOMAIN2.

And if the number in DOMAIN1 were to say, 1.1, *then* the result should say Bad.

Comment: Are you ever calling myversion1()?

Comment: I don't understand what you intend. `myVersion1` is a function, not a string and it doesn't return anything either.

Comment: What calls `myVersion1` and `myVersion2`?  What is `version-new.js`?

Comment: @user2651403: `myVersion1` and `myVersion2()` are function.  When ran, they both set the same variable: `window.domain2_version`.  Change one of them to set another variable, call both functions, then check the variables.

Comment: ok, but can you elaborate on what you mean by checking the variables?

Comment: where the heck is myVersion1 coming from?

Comment: @peterchon take a look at DOMAIN1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMAIN1:

```
function myVersion1(){window.domain1_version="1.0";}
```

DOMAIN2:

```
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/19653021128/version-new.js"></script>
<script>
  function myVersion2() {
    window.domain2_version = "1.0";
  }
  myVersion1();
  myVersion2();
  if (window.domain1_version == window.domain2_version) {
    document.write("Good");
  } else {
    document.write("Bad");
  }
</script>
```

**Optimized version**

DOMAIN1:

```
function myVersion1(){ return "1.0"; }
```

DOMAIN2:

```
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/19653021128/version-new.js"></script>
<script>
  function myVersion2() {
    return "1.0";
  }
  document.write(myVersion1() == myVersion2() ? "Good" : "Bad");
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to replace the content of **myVersion1** function with: `window.domain1_version = "1.0";`

Comment: THANK YOU, I HAD FIGURED OUT HOW TO DO IT WITH RETURNING A VALUE, THANKS TO @gstroup - I SAW YOU DID THE SAME METHOD SO THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3):

myVersion1 is a function, so it does not equal "1.0".  You have two functions, both are doing the same thing.  They both set window.domain2_version="1.0".  You might want your function to return a value, or else you could compare two different global variables.

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify: you don't know how to return a value from a function?

Comment: I also tried saying `if (myVersion1() == myVersion2())` but then all that happens is it ALWAYS says **Good** even when it's supposed to say **Bad** (It should say bad if for example `myVersion2()` says `1.1`)

Comment: @user2651403: `function myVersion1(){ return "1.0"; }`  Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: To return a value, you could add this line in a function:  return "1.0";

Comment: @gstroup THANK YOU I INSTEAD MADE IT RETURN A VALUE AND THEN COMPARED THE FUNCTIONS AGAINST EACH OTHER. IT WORKED!!! ADD IT AS AN ANSWER AND I WILL ACCEPT. HERE IS THE WORKING CODE!!! http://jsbin.com/UZAWeQi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @gstroup oh I just realized the original answer was by you! But I can't accept as best answer because the answer itself does not give the info I needed. If you update the answer with the code that I gave in the comment above, I'll accept you as best answer because you gave me the info first. Otherwise I can't accept as best answer because the other answer actually writes out the code in the answer.